# Is it possible to redirect input/output from fd other then stdin,stdout,stderr

Tags: linux, shell, piping

I'm aware of piping in linux shell (i have a very basic knowledge of it).

Lets say i have an executable that i know reads from a specific file (or from a socket), is it possible to redirect the output/input of this file using shell piping, like it is with stdin/out/err?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean `the output/input of this file`?

Comment: @alijandro i mean that if the program uses fread to read from a specific file, i'll be able to redirect the file output, so it won't be the file content itself but a string i provide, or the input of another file

Comment: This will not be possible, at least not with easy means like shell redirection. It is trivial to redirect input into a program, since almost all programs under *nix are designed to process just that by default, but if it _isn't reading standard input_ but instead some (possibly unknown) file, you're pretty much out of luck. It _might_ be possible to do some kind of hideous hack involving `/proc`, however (where all file descriptors are accessible). But that won't be easy, nor pretty, nor portable.

Comment: Since most "normal" programs do read standard input by default, may I guess this is a program you wrote yourself (or at least have access to source)? You might consider modifying it slightly so it reads stdin by default, and "some file" if you give it e.g. `-f somefile` on the commandline.

Comment: @Damon actually, my friend sent me the source code of a program running under linux with suid permissions. the program reads a file that only root can read, and matches it with a password the user enters to determine if they match. I needed to have the "access granted" message to apear, while i didn't had root privelages. i just thought it could be done using piping, but perhaps the program has some other security flaw. (he said it is hackable)

Comment: "if the program uses fread to read from a specific file, i'll be able to redirect the file output". This makes no sense whatsoever. A program reads from files X, Y, Z, and separately and independently writes to files A, B, and C. There is no such thing as "output of file X", there is only "output of the program".

Comment: @n.m. so how do you explain redirecting stdin? the program can use fread
from stdin aswell, so i assumed fread's input fd is redirectable

Comment: @n.m. Maybe i didn't explain myself properly, i want to redirect what fread reads, not a different file's output. if fread reads from a specific file, i want it to read from another file instead

Comment: If you _don't have_ root privilegues, there is no way of setuiding your program in a way so it will run with root privilegues. Luckily. The nature of this program sounds like it's not something I would like to run on my machine anyway. There are very few valid reasons (if any) for some arbitrary program to read the shadow file (which I assume is what he's trying since `/etc/passwd` doesn't need root privilegues). My guess is your "friend" is trying to steal your password...

Comment: @Damon nope, I run the program in his computer, and the program was already compiled, and with suid permissions. the source code was provided in the same directory.

Comment: If it's his computer and ready to run, what is the reason he needs to mail it to you, and you need to run it? The only imaginable reason can be that the compiled program secretly does something else in addition (like uploading the password file to a ftp server), and you are to be tricked into getting the idea _"Hey, this looks good, I should check whether my passwords are safe, too"_. This smells.

Comment: @Damon he didn't mail me the program. I said he sent me the source code for simplicity, as i didn't want to provide details i thought were not important. The code is surely hackable, and i didn't run it on my computer, but on his.

Comment: Redirection is only for file descriptors inherited from the parent process, not for those the program opens on its own.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, absolutely.  One way is to call [dup()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/dup) or [dup2()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/dup2) and close() the original file.  But of course, you'll need source code to modify the original program.